# Is it possible to make a generic function that takes different case classes

Tags: scala

#### Final Update/Verdict

Much to my surprise, Scala cannot easily solve such a problem without the use of a 3rd party library. Note that the linked duplicate question does not fulfill the request below.

---

#### Original Question

I'm part of a team which recently inherited a Scala project and want to make the code more DRY. I have 2 functions that are identical, but take and return a different case class. Is it possible to have **one** function take either case class?

I'm looking for a solution using standard Scala without the need to install 3rd party libraries.

I've already tried abstracting the function in many ways with no luck (i.e. using generic types, an `Either` type that accepts both case classes, using `asInstanceOf`).

Here's a dummy example to illustrate my problem:

```scala
trait Bird {
  val avgHeight: Int
}

case class Pigeon(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird
case class Ostrich(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird

def updateHeight(bird: ?): ? = {
  bird.copy(avgHeight = 2)
}

/*
def updateHeight[T <: Bird](bird: T): T = {
  val chosenBird = bird match {
    case _: Pigeon => bird.asInstanceOf[Pigeon]
    case _: Ostrich => bird.asInstanceOf[Ostrich]
  }

  chosenBird.copy(avgHeight = 2)
}
 */

println(updateHeight(Pigeon(1)))
println(updateHeight(Ostrich(1)))
```

---

### Update

Elaborating based on Mario's answer below. How do I remove the need to duplicate the conditional logic?:

```
sealed trait Bird {
  val avgHeight: Int
  val avgWidth: Int
  val wingSpan: Int
}

case class Pigeon(avgHeight: Int, avgWidth: Int, wingSpan: Int) extends Bird
case class Ostrich(avgHeight: Int, avgWidth: Int, wingSpan: Int) extends Bird

def updateBird(bird: Bird, height: Int, span: Int): Bird = {
  bird match {
    case p: Pigeon =>
      var newPigeon = p.copy(avgHeight = height)

      if (p.avgWidth.equals(0)) {
        newPigeon = newPigeon.copy(avgWidth = 100)
      }

      if (span > 0) {
        newPigeon = newPigeon.copy(wingSpan = span * 2)
      }

      newPigeon
    case o: Ostrich =>
      var newOstrich = o.copy(avgHeight = height)

      if (o.avgWidth.equals(0)) {
        newOstrich = newOstrich.copy(avgWidth = 100)
      }

      if (span > 0) {
        newOstrich = newOstrich.copy(wingSpan = span * 2)
      }

      newOstrich
  }
}

updateBird(Pigeon(1, 2, 3), 2, 0) // Pigeon(2,2,3)
updateBird(Ostrich(1, 0, 3), 2, 4) // Ostrich(2,100,8)
```

I'm looking for a truly DRY example where the primary code does not need to be duplicated: Here's an example in Typescript: https://repl.it/repls/PlayfulOverdueQuark

```
class Bird {
  avgHeight: Number
  avgWidth: Number
  wingSpan: Number

  constructor(avgHeight: Number, avgWidth: Number, wingSpan: Number) {
    this.avgHeight = avgHeight;
    this.avgWidth = avgWidth;
    this.wingSpan = wingSpan;
  }
}

class Pigeon extends Bird {}
class Ostrich extends Bird {}

const updateBird = (bird: Bird, height: Number, span: Number): Bird => {
  const newBird = Object.assign(
    bird,
    Object.create(
      bird instanceof Pigeon 
        ? bird as Pigeon 
        : bird as Ostrich
    )
  );

  // Update logic only happens below and is not 
  // duplicated based on the bird type

  if (bird.avgWidth === 0) {
    // Only update value if X condition is met
    // Condition based on passed in object
    newBird.avgWidth = 100
  }

  newBird.avgHeight = height;

  if (span > 0) {
    // Only update value if X condition is met
    newBird.wingSpan = Number(span) * 2;
  }

  return newBird;
}
```

Comment: This post is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745327/case-to-case-inheritance-in-scala
The accepted answer uses lenses to address a similar problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using [shapeless lenses](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/lenses.scala) as per Harald Gliebe's and Thilo's suggestion:

```
import shapeless._

object Hello extends App {
  sealed trait Bird {
    val avgHeight: Int
  }

  case class Pigeon(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird
  case class Ostrich(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird

  implicit val pigeonLens = lens[Pigeon].avgHeight
  implicit val ostrichLens = lens[Ostrich].avgHeight

  def updateHeight[T <: Bird](bird: T, height: Int)(implicit birdLense: Lens[T, Int]): T =
    birdLense.set(bird)(height)

  println(updateHeight(Pigeon(1), 2))
  println(updateHeight(Ostrich(1), 2))
}
```

which outputs

```
Pigeon(2)
Ostrich(2)
```

The linked typescript example is using mutable state to implement `updateHeight` however case class is an immutable structure. We could achieve similar like so

```
sealed trait Bird {
  val avgHeight: Int
}

case class Pigeon(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird
case class Ostrich(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird

def updateHeight(bird: Bird, height: Int): Bird =
  bird match {
    case _: Pigeon => Pigeon(height)
    case _: Ostrich => Ostrich(height)
  }

updateHeight(Pigeon(1), 2)
updateHeight(Ostrich(1), 2)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Bird = Pigeon(2)
res1: Bird = Ostrich(2)
```

Note how the compile time type is `Bird` but the runtime type is specialised `Pigeon` or `Ostrich`.

If the question is really about how to mutate an immutable case class, then we can simply use `copy` to create a new instance with changed height like so

```
Pigeon(1).copy(avgHeight = 2)
Ostrich(1).copy(avgHeight = 2)
```

which outputs

```
res2: Pigeon = Pigeon(2)
res3: Ostrich = Ostrich(2)
```

However if you would like to use immutable state like in the typescript example then try

```
class Bird(var avgHeight: Int)
class Pigeon(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird(avgHeight)
class Ostrich(avgHeight: Int) extends Bird(avgHeight)

def updateHeight(bird: Bird, height: Int): Bird = {
  bird.avgHeight = height
  bird
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. My apologizes if I'm mistaken, but doing it this way will not make the code any more DRY; you still have to duplicate all the logic in both HeightUpdaters, no? Keep in mind that the projects actual code does more than a single `copy`.

Comment: Using another strictly typed language as an example, you'll notice that there is no repetition: https://repl.it/repls/PlayfulOverdueQuark.

Comment: `updateHeight` from the Typescript linked example is not pattern matching on `bird` argument, and in fact is not using `bird` argument at all. It simply creates a new `Bird` instance, not a `Pigeon` or `Ostrich` specialisation. The linked example does not seem to be semantically the same as the original question.

Comment: Please see edited answer, however I am a bit unclear what the exact question is. Perhaps you can edit the question to add the typescript example to help others trying to answer.

Comment: I improved the typescript example (as you were right that it did not originally match the request) and added an update to the question.

Comment: I expanded on your codebase to better explain what I'm looking for.